# How many nutrients do trees process daily?

Tags: botany, plant-physiology, trees

Is this tree fact below that I have found on social media sites true? I don't know the source of the quote. It's pretty amazing. I'll be glad if someone can provide the source too!

> **Natural Wonders**
> Every day, a 40 foot tree takes in 50 gallons of dissolved nutrients from the soil, raises this mixture to its topmost leaves, converts it into 10 pounds of carbohydrates and releases about 60 cubic feet of pure oxygen into the air.

[image: transcription above]

Comment: There are 1000s of tree species that all vary in anatomy, morphology, & physiology; so, this type of generalization seems inappropriate & misleading. 2 trees of the same size but of different species would surely absorb/process nutrients at variable rates & in varying quantities. Further, even 2 trees of the same species would not experience consistent nutrient uptake & processing if environmental conditions (e.g., temperature, water availability, humidity, soil type, etc.) varied b/w each. Finally, trees of the same size aren't necessarily the same age, & age would impact these processes, too

Answer (score 2):

I don't know much about trees, but I was very skeptical about this post at first. If this web page is correct, then the post is actually not so far-fetched.

Trees are amazing. According to the page, the average tree absorbs 10,000 gallons of water and uses 1000 gallons, evaporating the rest. 24 gallons of water contains one pound of dry matter. That means that the average tree would accumulate almost 42 pounds of dry matter in a single day.

Now, I certainly cannot vouch for the credibility of the website, but it was difficult to find a page that showed the numbers, so take it with a grain of salt and try to find other sources that back it up or counter it.

Here's the link: https://www.thoughtco.com/process-of-using-water-by-trees-1343505

Answer (score 1):

We found the following link when search on the quote, the information is cited there:  http://gibneyce.com/tree-stats---classics.html

Cristina Hubbard, Executive Director
Forest Web

Answer (score 0):

### It's vague and hyperbolic.

The [USGS](https://www.usgs.gov/special-topic/water-science-school/science/evapotranspiration-and-water-cycle?qt-science_center_objects=0#qt-science_center_objects) water page says that a big oak tree can evaporate 40,000 gallons per year, that's 400 gallons per day for the growing season.

[This](http://www.tenmilliontrees.org/trees/) page also disagrees with the quote, giving less than half the figure, about 400 gallons per day for a 40 foot tree.

A 10x10 meter square of forest gains about 4 tons of weight per year, 11kg per day, so that fits in with the quote's estimate of 10 pounds per day.

So there is some truth to the quote for a hot day, it's overly generalized and vague.